# Calendar: How to limit the range of hours in Days display?

Tags: 7, datetime

I´m using the calendar module in d7.

In the  **Day** display it shows 01.00 to 23.00 in the hour column. How do I set it to be: 08.00 to 18.00?

I´m sure this is setteable in somewhere but I can´t find it...

I upload a picture which shows the hours to change:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the `Settings` of the Calendar format in the View and set the time grouping to `custom`.  In the box, specify the intervals/start times that you want to show up starting at the hour you want to start at.  See illustration below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It did the job. But to set the range (08:00 hs to 20:00 hs) I have to set the interval to: **08:00:00,09:00:00,10:00:00,11:00:00,12:00:00,13:00:00,14:00:00,15:00:00,16:00:00,17:00:00,18:00:00,19:00:00,20:00:00** Is there a shorter way??

Comment: @chefnelone not that I know of, but feel free to play around and test the values that you can put in that text box.