# Display three days in views (Calender style)

Tags: 7, views, datetime

How can i display the days in my views calender (Week view) like this way:
just three days

```
                      Today    |   tomorrow    |   after tomorrow
```

in this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11819/calendar-how-to-limit-the-range-of-hours-in-days-display) the solution for hours not for days, please put me in the right direction.